# libvpx not getting installed in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

When I use the command :

`sudo apt-get -f install libvpx*`

I get the following error :

```
Unpacking libvpx1 (from .../libvpx1_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libvpx1_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libvpx.so.1.0.0', which is also in package libvpx 110-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

But I checked `/usr/lib`
There is no libvpx.so.1.0.0 present in the directory.

Comment: It's not that the file exists already. It's that there is a *potential* conflict if you install both packages.

Answer (score 4):

If you only intend to install the `libvpx` library package, open a command terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>), and run the command `sudo apt-get install libvpx1`.

By, including the wildcard `*` in your command (using `libvpx*`), you are requesting a number of other files and potentially numerous dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the issue by following below mentioned steps :

Go to directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
Use the command :
sudo dpkg --unpack --force-all ./libvpx1_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

Note that using "force-all" option is important.

This forcefullly installed the libvpx debian package & the issue got solved.

Thanks for all the replies.